# How to allow an app to access internet on ios?

Tags: ios, vue.js, axios, nativescript, nativescript-vue

My Nativescript application works perfectly fine on Android but it doesn't connect to internet on ios. Either installed or simulated.

This is my store(where I use the internet):

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import axios from 'axios/dist/axios';

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://asdfasdf.compute.amazonaws.com',
  timeout: 2000,
});

Vue.use(Vuex);
export default new Vuex.Store({
  strict: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  state: {
    name: null,
    err: null,
  },
  mutations: {
    initialize(state, name) {
      state.name = name;
    },
    err(state, txt) {
      state.err = txt;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    init({commit}) {
      api
        .get('/name/')
        .then(response => {
          commit('initialize', response.data);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
          commit('err', error);
        });
    },
  },
});
```

I get the name loaded just fine on my android installation, 
But on ios emulator and iPhone installation I get:

> Error: Request failed with status code null

Any thoughts how I can fixed this? I don't get any errors or exceptions anywhere, also I get the exact same error if I disconnect my phone from the internet. I'm not using any proxy.

Comment: Use Https or disable ATS https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible problem is ATS you can read [here](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/app-transport-security-blocks-ajax-calls/7849)

What you need to do is adding the following snippet into `app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist`.
There is a `<dict>` tag in there with a lot of content in it. All you need to do is putting this inside that `<dict>`

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

So you will get something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
    # snippet goes here
    .
    .
    .
    </dict>
</plist>
```

You also need to do this if your server is using a self-signed certificate.

Comment: My server doesn't actually have a certificate yet. It's http only.

Comment: is it by IP or you have DNS name?

Comment: I have a long dns name from aws.

Comment: than test this and please let me know if you still have a problem

Comment: In the link that I send you is written where it is. It should be in /template/app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist

Comment: You have to insert this snippet inside the dict tag of your Info.plist.

Comment: @yukashimahuksay is it okay?

Comment: I added the snippet, but still getting 'Request failed with status code null' error for my self-signed local https API endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Problem was gone after editing Info.plist file that allow specific domains rather than all domains. and I heard that if you trying upload your app in app store it will be rejected in iOS 10 + if you allow all http domains.

Here is my App Transport Security

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
            <dict>
                <key>specificDomain.com</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                    <true/>
                    <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                    <false/>
                </dict>
            </dict>
        <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```